# POCO C++ Framework library usage in embedded systems

Tags: c++, networking, poco, poco-libraries

Actually we are planning to use POCO C++ library for our communication framework. Just wanted to check will the library work for embedded systems as well. We have to get it running on an arm processor.

E.g. does it support LWIP sockets ??

Comment: What particular CPU are you going to use? Should it run Linux? How big is your flash storage? POCO is running without issues on  a ar9331 MIPS machine running Linux. It is also an embedded system, but it is not the same as Cortex-M0 controllers.

Comment: I can provide the exact spec. Is there a way to attach a pdf

Comment: Exact specs are not needed. Just update your question with exact model and perhaps a link to the data sheet and write, what OS you're going to use.

Comment: https://www.digi.com/products/embedded-systems/system-on-modules/connectcore-for-i-mx6ul

Comment: This is a "monster" SoC providing at least 256MB NAND/RAM. Why would you want to use lwIP on such a system? According to lwIP project's page, lwIP suitable for use in embedded systems with tens of kilobytes of free RAM and room for around 40 kilobytes of code ROM.

Comment: @yegorich. Thanks a lot. We have another board which is having these configurations:
Memories
– Up to 2 MB of Flash memory organized into
two banks allowing read-while-write
– Up to 256+4 KB of SRAM including 64-KB
of CCM (core coupled memory) data RAM
– Flexible external memory controller with up
to 32-bit data bus:
SRAM,PSRAM,SDRAM/LPSDR SDRAM ,
Compact Flash/NOR/NAND memories

Answer (score 1):

As the question is not very specific, I can only assume some details:

POCO itself can be run on various platforms, you can compile it using `--config=<configuration>` option. Available configurations contain at least `ARM-Linux`. I assume, that is the target you are looking for.

`lwIP` sockets are, as far as I know, based on [this](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/lwip/) library. That is separate library but especially suitable for embedded systems. It has nothing to do with POCO though. It has ports for various ARM devices, but some of them are harder to find. Eg. see some older mailing-list issues:

http://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/lwip-users/2006-06/msg00043.html
http://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/lwip-users/2012-01/msg00009.html

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Just wanted to understand has anyone used POCO for embedded systems where we might have to use the lwIP socket library